# TRIMMEAN in MDX

Tags: mdx, mdxstudio

In Excel I can use this formula to calculate the average in a certain period and ignore the top 20% most extreme values: TRIMMEAN(AY13:BH13,20%)

I cannot find any result when searching on MDX TRIMMEAN. I think I have to do something with RANK and calculate the average by ignore X from the top and the bottom of the ranked result. Does somebody have an example of something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BottomPercent`. From Microsoft's documentation, if you want to find the measure value in the bottom 80% (exclude the top 20%), then you can have something like this:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ON 0,  
BottomPercent  
   ({[Geography].[Geography].[City].Members}  
   , 80  
   , [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]  
   ) ON 1  
FROM [Adventure Works]  
WHERE([Product].[Product Categories].[Bikes])
```

Further details can be found here [BottomPercent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/bottompercent-mdx)

Comment: Thanks. TRIMMEAN cuts from both the top and the bottom. So if I want the middle 80%, I should first do BottomPercent with 90 and TopPercent with 89?